# Internet DNS resolution is too slow

Tags: networking, dns

My internet connection at work is too slow. This does not happen when using a computer in the same office running Windows, but does happen in my main computer, running Linux (Manjaro).

The problem is establishing a connection. Once it is set, then I have the same download speed as anyone else. For instance, the problem is reaching the youtube.com page, not watching a video.

For example, if I open the terminal and time a ping to youtube, until the first packet has arrived:

```
time ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com (216.58.211.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C64 bytes from 216.58.211.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=13.6 ms

--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.613/13.613/13.613/0.000 ms

real    0m9,098s
user    0m0,004s
sys     0m0,000s
```

It results in nine seconds!

I thought the problem could be the DNS. My `resolv.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search esei.uvigo.es
nameserver 4.4.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

That's why I tried to avoid any DNS server here at work. But unfortunately it did not solve anything. I'm not so sure DNS is the problem anymore.

How could I diagnose the problem better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.4.4.4 is not a public DNS server.

This explains the delay before the initial connection is established, as your system will first try to query 4.4.4.4, wait for a timeout and will then skip to the next resolver in the resolv.conf list, 8.8.8.8, which will succeed.

Change 4.4.4.4 to 8.8.4.4 (the other official Google DNS Server) or experiment with other public DNS servers like OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220).

Comment: From what I remember, it _is_ a DNS server, but private and only accessible to GTE or Verizon customers (and OP is in another country). Either that, or OP confused it with `4.2.2.2` or `4.2.2.4` (both of which are public Level3 DNS resolvers).

Comment: You may be right, but I can't access it from my location and it isn't listed as an official public DNS anywhere AFAIK.

Comment: Many thanks! Now I feel quite stupid, but at least it works flawlessly now.